# Who sees my posts shared with “Extended Circles” in their stream?

Tags: google-plus

I'm not sure my own answer to this guestion is correct:
[When to post to "Extended Circles"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/when-to-post-to-extended-circles/17448)

When I wrote that question and answer, I thought that sharing to "extended circles" would actively push my posts not just into the streams of those having circled me but *also* into the streams of those who've circled *them.* That can't be right, because clearly there would be a large amount of posts in my own incoming stream from people I haven't circled. So what correct, then?

**Is "extended circles" actually a narrow version of "public"?** "Public" doesn't push my posts to anyone's streams but it makes the posts visible to *anyone* who comes looking.

**Am I right in assuming that** "extended circles" also doesn't push my posts to anyone's streams but it makes the posts visible to *anyone who is in a circle of someone whom I have circled?*

Answer (score 3):

In Google+ you only see posts in your Stream from people you follow yourself. But of course, that person can decide itself whether or not it shows up in your Stream.

Sharing to Circles and Extended Circles (in the circles of someone in your circles) just gives the people in your circles and those in their circles **the right** to see your post in their Stream **if they are following you**.

So if you have people in your circles that don't have you in theirs, they won't see your posts shared with them in their Streams. Only if f.e. I am following you and you appear to be following someone that follows me, I will see your Extended Circles post while I'm not in your circles.

I hope this gives a good explanation. It would be wrong to be able to push posts in someone's Stream without having them chose for it, right?

Btw, also, when f.e. someone would be in your Extended Circles but is not following you, he will also be able to see the post when he gets a link to it. So, when you get a link to a post, you will be able to see it when you fall under the audience of the post (either a circle, all the poster's circles/Extended Circles or Public).