# Why is someone not allowed to see my private video on YouTube even though I have shared it with them?

Tags: youtube, privacy, sharing

I have added their email address to the list of people who can view my private video. Why are they getting a notification that the video is private? I have noticed that their email address shows up as "name unavailable". Does this have something to do with it and why is it happening?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? It's driving me crazy. I want a set of videos to appear as 'public' to the users I shared them with. (e.g. show up in searches, show on my channel, show in playlists, etc). Just ONLY to those people. I don't want unlisted.

Comment: These answers do not help. Again I'll repeat: - I make a video private - I share the video with UserA only. - UserB views my channel and sees no videos. **Correct!** - UserA views my channel **AND SEES NO VIDEOS. WRONG!!!** I **DO NOT** want to share the url with UserA! I want them to see my shared video right in my channel as if it was a public video. It's shared with them. Why do they need a Url?

Comment: @melissa Do you use and old YouTube Channel (made before 2009) and/or are you already using Google+ Circles for privacy controls?

Answer (score 5):

Quote from [YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177) about Video privacy settings:

> A private video can only be seen by you and the users that YOU select.

You have to **select a real User with a Google Account** (formerly known as YouTube Account). This means that the eMail Addresses you select (when sharing privately) have to be the same as those used to login by their respective Users.

---

When YouTube is used in conjunction with a linked Google+ Profile or G+ (business) Page, then the sharing works differently. Privacy is then controlled via the Circles Feature.

Questions to ask yourself:

- Have you linked your YouTube Channel to a G+ Profile or a Google+ Page?
- Did you setup your Circles (to manage Contacts)?

There are 2 groups you have to understand:

- Your Circles
- Extended Circles

---

For a better understanding of how the Google+ Circle Concept works, please checkout the following links:

- Read this Quick Tip: [What does "Extended Circles" mean?](http://www.googleplusdaily.com/2013/03/quick-tip-what-does-extended-circles.html) | by +GooglePlusDaily
- [Who sees my posts shared with “Extended Circles” in their stream?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30594/who-sees-my-posts-shared-with-extended-circles-in-their-stream) | WebApps StackExchange

Answer (score 2):

They need to have a Google account (and of course you have to send the invite to the Google account + they need to sign in to watch the video): https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en

> You can add the profiles or email addresses of the people with whom
>   you’d like to share your video. They’ll need a Google account to view
>   your video.

Comment: Yes, we all have Google accounts. The main account uploads the videos and marks them private. They then share the videos to another user. The other user logs in and cannot see ANY videos in the channel. It simply does not work. We are not willing to share each video each time. I want the other user to see all videos that are shared with them which is not happening. Yes the individual link works but this is a terrible solution and won't work.

Comment: @Paul Did you share like this webapps.stackexchange.com/a/7613/18147 ?